# pytest: capture stdout/stderr at setup/teardown

Tags: docker, pytest

In my tests, I use fixture to run a web server Docker container via [docker-py](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html#docker.models.containers.ContainerCollection.run) and `detach=True`.

When test is executed, I want to output container logs in case of failure. This is in principle achieved with

```
print(container.logs().decode(), file=sys.stderr)
```

on fixture teardown; but I get logs even for successful tests, not only for failed ones as if I printed the logs in the test body.

What's the best way to output the logs so the behavior is similar to printing them in the test bodies as they come?

Comment: Check out the recipe [Making test result information available in fixtures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html#making-test-result-information-available-in-fixtures). Once you have the custom `pytest_runtest_makereport` hook added, you can control what you print in your fixture and when, like shown in the recipe: `if request.node.rep_setup.failed: print(container.logs().decode())` etc.

Comment: Thanks, that's quite close! But unfortunately that doesn't respect e.g. `-s` flag (disable capture). I want the output printed even for successful tests if `-s` is specified (as if I was printing the logs as they come in the test body).